# Mobiscroll date picker inside ChocolatechipUI popover?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, popover, mobiscroll

I'm trying to get the [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) date picker inside a [chocolatechipUI](http://www.chocolatechip-ui.com/tutorials.html) popover. For the moment I have tried putting the input text field inside the popover to see if the positioning of the datepicker was relative to the parent element. The date picker is shown in the middle of the page not inside the popover which is my goal.

Create the popover:

```
$.UIPopover(popover2);
var popover3 = {
    triggerElement: "#showPopover3", 
    popoverOrientation: "top", 
    pointerOrientation: "right", 
    id: "popover3", 
    title: "Popover Three"
};
```

Add content:

```
$("#popover3 scrollpanel").append('<input type="text" class="mobiscroll" id="datePicker"/>');
```

Bind the click to a button:

```
$("#showPopover3").bind("click", function() {
    $.UIPopover.show($("#popover3"));
```

Any help on how get this working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2.0 inline mode was introduced. Try to put an inline scroller in your popup.
For an example see http://demo.mobiscroll.com

Comment: what is inline mode , can you please explain as dome has several examples

Comment: Sure... There are several display modes. Modal (popup in the middle of the screen), Bubble (popup next to bind element), Top/Bottom (popup at the top or bottom of the screen) and Inline (rendering without a popup) - See example: http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/date/#display=inline